# ImportError: No module named six [Windows]

Tags: python, windows, opencv, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('test.jpg',0)       
orb = cv2.ORB()   
kp = orb.detect(img,None) 
kp, des = orb.compute(img, kp)   
img2 = cv2.drawKeypoints(img,kp,color=(0,255,0), flags=0)
plt.imshow(img2),plt.show()
```

I download six 1.9.0 from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six . But I copy it to "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib" directory. But it doesn't work. I got the error:

> ImportError: No module named six

Comment: What is the Traceback? I don't see you have imported `six` anywhere?

Comment: **What** did you copy to that directory? The `.whl`? The `.tar.gz` file? Why did you copy it to the `matplotlib` directory? If you downloaded the `.whl`, why didn't you use pip to install it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have pip configured, you can run

```
$ pip install six
```

or (for python 3)

```
$ pip3 install six
```